# Magento 2 system variable for "Order Created at" for email templates

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email, email-templates, variables

What is the email template system variable for "Order Created at" for **Magento ver. 2.2.6**?

Using the variable name: `{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}` doesn't work for me. This is a variable applied using the Magento UI:

[image]

I looked into the devdocs and the is no variable for this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html

In addition, why are the varibale names different from when you using Magento UI and when looking at the devdocs? E.g:

Getting billing address:

1. Using UI: `{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}`
2. Devdocs: `{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}`

*NOTE*: I had to use the devdocs variable names for it to work properly.

Comment: It is not order.getCreatedAtFormatted. It is $order.getCreatedAtFormatted. Notice the $ (dollar sign) before order object.

Comment: Just tried it... No luck still. Also, why would it be added without the "$" by default using UI?

Comment: $order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw This is the function already available in magento2 order templates

Comment: Whoopp. At the end this worked for me: `{{var order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2)|raw}}`. You helped anyway :) Thank you kindly.

Comment: Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: is there a way to show only the date, so without the time (hours and minutes) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2)|raw}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set `is_legacy` column in `email_template` table to `1`

or use `{{var created_at_formatted}}` variable instead (but it doesn't available for shipping, creditmemo and invoice emails)

The reason is that `Magento\Framework\Filter\VariableResolverStrictResolver\StrictResolver` doesn't provide `handleObjectMethod()` method (and `Magento\Framework\Filter\VariableResolver\LegacyResolver` does)